# Dropdown menu disappears when mouse moves over the WHO WE SUPPLY tab

Tags: wordpress

Recently i encountered a problem with the dropdown menu called "WHO WE SUPPLY". The main_menu disappear just when i move my cursor over them. I have tried the other answers to similar questions like this but they were not of great help in my case.

I just want the dropdown elements to remain at their places when i move my mouse over them so that i can select them.
Can anyone please check the problem?
My website link is http://effortlessled.com/ 
Try to go to the WHO WE SUPPLY tab and you will see what exactly i am saying.

Many thanx in advance..
..hope to get a reply soon !!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the "color" property of your "Who We Supply" anchor tag is getting overridden by some other class's color property and the firebug is pointing to line #530 of your style.css file.

The color property mentioned there is "#FFFFFF" which is for white color.
So change the color of that particular class.

Basically the link is not hidden just the color property of that link changes on Hover event to White which is same as your background color